# where to find an example png file which has date and time metadata that eye-of-gnome (eog) shows

Tags: gnome, time, date, metadata, png

I'm using xubuntu 20.04 and have installed the eye-of-gnome (eog) on it.

The version of eog is GNOME Image Viewer 3.36.3

On the right side of the eog window (which is called "Image Viewer") there's a column of "Properties".  This includes Size, Type, File Size, and several other items, and it ends with Date and Time.

For the photographic jpg files that i have the Date and Time fields are populated.

But for the png files that i have, the Date and Time fields are blank.

So i would like to find a png file somewhere which has sufficient metadata for eog to show a Date and a Time.  (Then, i can analyze the file and see what metadata is needed, and how to encode it.)

Could anybody please point to some place i could download a png file whose Date and Time will show up in eog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like with the current version of eog this is not possible.

The deal is that the date displayed comes from the exif data.  Exif data is collected from jpg files in eog-metadata-reader-jpg.c.  But in eog-metadata-reader-png.c, which gets metadata for png files, no effort is made to read any exif chunks.  So no date will be displayed for png files.

Note that if the eog authors read and parsed the text chunks, then there are standard places the date could be read.  However, that would require a structural change to eog.

Leaving the question up in hopes the answer will change.